# Show connected wifi password C#

Tags: c#, networking, wifi

I create a program where when I copy "WiFi status" a Windows message with the SSID and the single strength is displayed. Now I also want the option to get the WiFi password, but I don't know how to do that. because if I do the command `wlan show profile "+ s1 +" key = clear "`, he also can't show me the password when I do`string s3 = s.Substring (s.IndexOf ("Key Content"));`can someone help me

This is my code:

```
if (clipboardText == "wifi status")
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan show interfaces";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();
    string s = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string s1 = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("SSID"));
    s1 = s1.Substring(s1.IndexOf(":"));
    s1 = s1.Substring(2, s1.IndexOf("\n")).Trim();

    string s2 = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("Signal"));
    s2 = s2.Substring(s2.IndexOf(":"));
    s2 = s2.Substring(2, s2.IndexOf("\n")).Trim();

    {
        notifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Exclamation;
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "";
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "WIFI verbonden met " + s1 + "  " + "Signaal sterkte " + s2;
        notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
        notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do that in C#. But I did find [this](https://github.com/codingo/Retrieve-Windows-Wifi-Passwords) which might help. If it doesn't work - try running it as admin.

Comment: This is confusing. You're calling `netsh wlan show interfaces` which shows you the network hardware interface, not the stored WiFi settings. If you want the output of `netsh wlan show profile SSID_name key=clear` then you should call that..?

Comment: My computer can't find that command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039148/how-can-i-get-connected-wifi-password-in-my-code-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

To see the WiFi profile password using the `netsh` tool, you must run it under the administrative privileges.

Use this command:

```
netsh wlan show profile <SSID_name> key=clear
```

Add

```
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

to your process startup configuration.

Comment: But how can i show the wifi password in my c# code?

Comment: I want the key content but i dont know how to get it in my windows notification

Answer (score 0):

```
 Process processWifi = new Process();
        processWifi.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        processWifi.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh";
        processWifi.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan show profile";
        processWifi.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processWifi.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processWifi.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processWifi.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processWifi.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processWifi.Start();
        string output = processWifi.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string err = processWifi.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        processWifi.WaitForExit();
        return output;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are generally less helpful than answers with an explanation. Please explain what this does and why it's a good solution to the problem. Thanks!